# Understanding order_by of multi-valued fields (Django)

Tags: django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

Having read the [django docs on `order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) there is a note/warning that (if I have understood correctly) says that:

- If you are ordering a queryset using a multi-valued field, then every element in that queryset that has multiple related items, will be added multiple times to the resulting queryset created by `order_by`.

I tried testing this out with a basic example:

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField('Topping', through='PizzaToppings')

class PizzaToppings(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey('Pizza', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pizza_toppings")
    topping = models.ForeignKey('Topping', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pizzas_with_topping")
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["amount",]

class Topping(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then

```
>>> p1 = Pizza.objects.create(name="Cheese and Tomato")
>>> p2 = Pizza.objects.create(name="Pepperoni")
>>> cheese = Topping.objects.create(ingredient="Cheese")
>>> tomato = Topping.objects.create(ingredient="Tomato puree")
>>> p1.toppings.add(cheese, through_defaults={"amount":4})
>>> p1.toppings.add(tomato, through_defaults={"amount":3})
>>> p2.toppings.add(cheese, through_defaults={"amount":2})
>>> p2.toppings.add(tomato, through_defaults={"amount":1})
```

So far, so normal. But this is where things get confusing:

```
>>> q1 = Topping.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Topping: Topping object (1)>, <Topping: Topping object (2)>]>
>>> q2 = p1.toppings.all()
<QuerySet [<Topping: Topping object (1)>, <Topping: Topping object (2)>]>
>>> q1.order_by("pizzas_with_topping")
<QuerySet [<Topping: Topping object (2)>, <Topping: Topping object (1)>, <Topping: Topping object (2)>, <Topping: Topping object (1)>]>
>>> q2.order_by("pizzas_with_topping")
<QuerySet [<Topping: Topping object (2)>, <Topping: Topping object (1)>]>
```

#### The problem

As can be seen above, the querysets are identical in terms of the elements that they contain. But when one `q1` is ordered we get the behaviour described in the documentation. In `q2` we don't get that behaviour. Presumably this is because django is doing something clever since the queryset is concerned with toppings related to `p1`.

#### The question(s)

What is actually going on 'under the hood' to enforce this behaviour? The querysets are the same (if I have understood correctly), so why does `order_by` behave differently for the two querysets.

Comment: If you order by, you make a `JOIN`, for `q1`, this will thus join on `PizzaToppings`. For the latter the querset *is* already joined due to filtering, and thus you eliminate certain rows in the JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two querysets are different. The first queryset represents a query like:

```
-- q1
SELECT *
FROM topping
```

The query that is represented by `q2` looks like:

```
-- q2
SELECT *
FROM topping
INNER JOIN pizzatoppings ON pizzatoppings.topping_id = topping.id
WHERE pizzatoppings.pizza_id = id-of-pizza
```

If you then perform a `.order_by('pizzas_with_topping')`, then you thus make a `JOIN` on the table of the `PizzaToppings` model, and you thus order by the primary key of that table. For the first queryset this thus looks like:

```
-- q1.order_by('pizzas_with_topping')
SELECT *
FROM topping
LEFT OUTER JOIN pizzatoppings ON pizzatoppings.topping_id = topping.id
ORDER BY pizzatoppings.id
```

for the latter you filter on the join that already exists:

```
-- q2.order_by('pizzas_with_topping')
SELECT *
FROM topping
INNER JOIN pizzatoppings ON pizzatoppings.topping_id = topping.id
WHERE pizzatoppings.pizza_id = id-of-pizza
ORDER BY pizzatoppings.id
```

this thus means that if the same topping is used for multiple pizzas, for `q1`, it will appear each time for each pizza whereas for `q2` we already have filtered on the pizza, and thus retrieve each `Topping` for that pizza, not the other ones.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the very thorough explanation :) Makes sense